# Python variable not changed during a function

Tags: python-2.7, variables, global

I came accross a problem 2 days ago and I couldn't find a way to make it work, it's simple and my solution seems "good" to me. 
Here is what I got :

```
leftKeyCounter = 0

def sendCommand():
    # I want to get the counter back to 0.
    leftKeyCounter = 0
    return leftKeyCounter

while True:
...
leftKeyCounter = leftKeyCounter + 1
```

The sendCommand() function is called automatically every 5 seconds with the "schedule" helper. 
In my terminal, the "leftKeyCounter" is not changed, for example; if it is 4, when the function is run, it tells me the variable is 0 now, but if i add one again, it's 5...

All the solutions I look for send me back to the "global variable" that has been deprecated, so I don't find a working solution...

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You just need to add `global leftKeyCounter` in the `sendCommand()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to global scope variables, and **modify** them, then you can do the following thing:

```
leftKeyCounter = 0

def sendCommand():
    # I want to get the counter back to 0.
    global leftKeyCounter
    leftKeyCounter = 0
    return leftKeyCounter

while True:
...
leftKeyCounter = leftKeyCounter + 1
```

This question had already been answered: [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: I will try it right now, and I already came across this post you're refering to, but i thought it was deprecated, I've read it at so many places, that's why I didn't wan't to use the global var way... (the post is from 2009, so... ), thanks

Answer (score 4):

The reason its doing this, is because the `leftKeyCounter` inside your method is different than the `lefKeyCounter` defined outside - even if they have the same name.

One way to make the method modify the `leftKeyCounter` that is defined outside, is to use the `global` keyword - so it knows that it is modifying the *global version* of the variable.

Another way is to pass the variable in, and return the modified value, and then save this return value:

```
def sendCommand(leftKeyCounter):
   # do something here
   if something_is_true:
       leftKeyCounter = 0
   return leftKeyCounter # this is the new value of leftKeyCounter

leftKeyCounter = 0 # this is the starting value
while True:
   # do something here
   leftKeyCounter = sendCommand(leftKeyCounter)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed !

Answer (score 2):

This is a scoping issue.

sendCommand -> leftKeyCounter is not the same as leftKeyCounter - it'll tell you it's 0 because within the scope of the function it is.

This stack overflow question has some excellent answers and information about how this works. [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: Thanks ! Will take a look :)